# cabal-install does not retain the version for happy

Tags: haskell, cabal-install, happy

I've trying to do `cabal install hoogle` but there is a hickup with the `haskell-src-exts-1.13.5` dependency:

```
Configuring haskell-src-exts-1.13.5...
setup: The program happy version >=1.17 is required but it could not be found.
```

When I try to do `cabal install happy` it seems to finish successfully, but cabal-install does not retain the version:

```
>$ cabal list happy
* happy
    Synopsis: Happy is a parser generator for Haskell
    Default available version: 1.18.10
    Installed versions: [ Unknown ]
    Homepage: http://www.haskell.org/happy/
    License:  BSD3
```

As you can see the version is `[ Unknown ]`. It stays unknown, and cabal-install remains oblivious if I try to run `cabal install happy` again.

What gives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ⁺¹ for the point that the `happy` is a program name, it wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Looks like cabal does not show `Installed versions` for executables, but for libraries only.

Maybe cabal install `happy` somewhere to your home directory, for example in `$HOME/.cabal/bin`, and it's not in your `PATH`. `cabal install happy` show this path in some last lines. So you can add this path to your `PATH` and try to install `haskell-src-exts` again.

Comment: Thanks! Having $HOME/.cabal/bin in the path is what did it, since cabal puts the executables in that directory.

Comment: Thanks for this! On my mac, `happy` was placed in `$HOME/Library/Haskell/bin` incase thats helpful to anyone. I was also confused at why cabal wasn't listing it right after an install.

Comment: On MinGHC this meant putting `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\cabal\bin` in my path before the MinGHC bin so that the latest version of cabal, happy and alex were used